# Basic Discrete Mathematics Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I was preparing my self before an exam and I found this question:

For each of the following equations, find a positive integer $n$ that satisfies the equation.  The notation $p(n,r)$ stands for $n(n-1)\ldots(n-r+1).$

$p(n,2) = 30$

$p(n,3)=24p(n,2)$

$10p(n,2)=p(3n-1,2)+40$

How can I solve this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What does p stands for?

Comment: What do $p$ and $n$ stand for, and what does the $()$ notation mean?

Comment: I don't know,this is the exercise....

Comment: Sorry guys that is all the information that was given...
And it's the reason that I am asking you about that ,I hoped that you could help me with that.

Comment: Apply the definition of $p$ to your problems, you will obtain quadratic or cubic equations. It's easy to solve them.

Answer (score 1):

Once you expand the $p$ notation, these problems ask you to solve the following equations for $n$, where $n$ is a positive integer:

1. $n(n-1)=30$
2. $n(n-1)(n-2)=24n(n-1)$
3. $10n(n-1)=(3n-1)(3n-2)+40$

The first can easily  be solved by eye, and the second almost as easily; in neither case should you have to set and solve an equation. You will probably have to do so for the third, but the equation is only a quadratic and therefore easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is not a single problem, but three separate problems.  The notation $p(n,r)$ most likely stands for $n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-r+1),$ the number of ways to fill $r$ slots with elements taken from a set of size $n.$  Each exercise then boils down to some algebra.

Comment: So, for example, in the first problem you have $p(n,2)=n(n-1)=30$ or $n^2-n-30=0$ or $(n-6)(n+5)=0$.  So $n=6.$  The others are similar.

Comment: @Gil: I made an edit to your question.  Please let me know if you believe any of the changes to be incorrect.